# Tiling (repeating / wrapping) XYZ tiles across the date line in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, xyz-tiles

My question is the same as one [unanswered for three years on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/QGIS/comments/g7szcl/qgis_repeat_grid_for_infinite_map_canvas_in/), but I thought this community might have an answer. When adding XYZ tiles in QGIS, such as OpenStreetMap tiles, the layer only extends to ±180 degrees longitude, instead of repeating. This is inconvenient when working on a map close to the date line.

Is there a way to repeat the tiles, perhaps by using a custom projection with a false easting?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of wrapping / tiling / repeating, I realised it is probably better to change the map projection so it is centred on the Pacific (e.g. EPSG: 3832), as shown in [this example](https://www.gislounge.com/center-map-pacific-ocean-using-qgis/).